# High crash rate due to Android web view's SIGTRAP crashes

Tags: android, flutter, webview, android-webview

We are experiencing a lot of crashes (2% crash rate because of them) that look like this:
[image]

As far as I know, they are impossible to catch because they happen deep inside the internals. Right now the solution is to warn users to update their web view and chrome but it seems to have little effect. We also tried using `onRenderProcessGone` method, but it didn't have any effect.

Is there any way to solve this or understand where the issue is? I have even thought of using GeckoView but I wonder if it won't come with its own issues.

Our app is a Flutter app which uses web view to achieve most of its functionality. We use InAppWebView wth these options:

```
return InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      javaScriptEnabled: true,
      javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true),
  android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
    useHybridComposition: true,
    supportMultipleWindows: true,
  ),
  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    applePayAPIEnabled: _applePayEnabled,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest this is related to unhandled exceptions within the webview itself. There must be something loading in the webview that is creating an edge case crash.

What I suggest is try running the same in an Android Native App if you can. There you will be able to actual debug the webview functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can also manage it by disposing of the controller at the right time when we change the screen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing many issues with webview in flutter. but now the time changed. flutter_inappwebview released their new pre release version. its just awesome.

i suggest you to use that version [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/6.0.0-beta.25)

This is my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class WebViewXPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewXPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewXPage> createState() => _WebViewXPageState();
}

class _WebViewXPageState extends State<WebViewXPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  bool isLoading = true;
  int progress = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Check if webview can go back
        if (await webViewController!.canGoBack()) {
          // Go back
          webViewController!.goBack();
          // Return false so this webview won't be popped
          return false;
        } else {
          // Let system handle back button
          return true;
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              InAppWebView(
                onPermissionRequest: (controller, onPermissionRequest) async {
                 return PermissionResponse(
                    resources: onPermissionRequest.resources,
                    action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT,
                  );
                },
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                  url: WebUri("https://snopixie.com/login/"),
                ),
                initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
                  mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
                  allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                  allowBackgroundAudioPlaying: true,
                  useHybridComposition: false,
                  allowFileAccess: true,
                ),
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  webViewController = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = true;
                    progress = 0;
                  });
                },
                onProgressChanged: (controller, p) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = p < 100;
                    progress = p;
                  });
                },
                onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                    progress = 0;
                  });
                },
                onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {},
              ),
              if (isLoading)
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor:
                          const AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      value: progress / 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```